# Understanding syntax in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to use PodSixNet library in Python to implement a multiplayer game. As I have seen a few tutorials online, the server file is as follows:

```
import PodSixNet.Channel
import PodSixNet.Server
from time import sleep

class ClientChannel(PodSixNet.Channel.Channel):
    def Network(self, data):
        print data

class BoxesServer(PodSixNet.Server.Server):
    channelClass = ClientChannel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         PodSixNet.Server.Server.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

What does the line `channelClass = ClientChannel`mean?

`channelClass` is definitely not an instance of the `ClientChannel` class because the instance declaration is not correct. So what is it then?

Comment: It's not an instance, it's a reference to the class itself.

Comment: And Python does not have declarations. You just assign variables without declaring them.

Comment: It assigns the class `ClientChannel` to the "class property" `channelClass`. No more, no less. Likely some code within `PodSixNet.Server.Server.__init__` is going to pick up on that property and do something with the class.

Comment: You are assigning ClientChannel as channelClass.

Comment: You are assigning `ClientChannel`, a **class** (the class object itself, not one of its instances) to `BoxesServer.channelClass`, a **class attribute** (shared by all instances of that class). This attribute is then used by instances of the class; see https://github.com/chr15m/PodSixNet/blob/master/PodSixNet/Server.py#L32

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All this does is create the `BoxesServer.channelClass` class attribute. It is just a reference to another class.

Why would you do that? Well, the `PodSixNet.Server.Server` is flexible, it doesn't hardcode the class it'll use to create channels for new connections. Instead, it'll look for the `self.channelClass` attribute, and use that to create new channel instances. See the [`Server.handle_accept()` method source](https://github.com/chr15m/PodSixNet/blob/master/PodSixNet/Server.py#L22-L35):

```
self.channels.append(self.channelClass(conn, addr, self, self._map))
```

Calling `self.channelClass()` then creates an instance of whatever class is assigned to that attribute. This lets you swap out the channel class easily when defining new subclasses.

Note that the `PodSixNet.Server.Server()` class can also take the channel class as an argument when creating an instance. That'll then override the class attribute you set.

Answer (score 1):

This is meant for deferred use.

Later on, any instantiation of `channelClass` will result in `ClientChannel` instances.

See this as a way to allow the developer to use whatever class he wants, but the `PodSixNet.Server.Server` subclasses will always instantiate `channelClass` as **they cannot know what real class will be given by the developer**.

Answer (score 0):

In python classes are first class objects. You can assign them to a variable just like any other object. The `channelClass = ClientChannel` means to assign to `BoxesServer.channelClass` the class `ClientChannel` (as a class variable), later `BoxesServer.channelClass` can be used just like `ClientChannel`.

This could be useful if you derive from `BoxesServer` and then assign in the derived class another class for `channelClass` which would mean that you can customize which class to be used in place of `ClientChannel`. You can for example in a method write:

```
def getChannelInstance(self, *args, **kwds):
     return self.channelClass(*args, **kwds)
```

...and it will return an instance as appropriate depending on the class.